# How to merge my two python scripts in one?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, ipywidgets

I want to create a web interface with a python srcipt in order to generate different graph from many CSV.

For that, I use pandas, plotly avec ipywidgets as librarys and Jupyter Notebook.

My first script allow to display a CSV according to the server and the date choose in the dropdowns :

```
from ipywidgets import interact, Dropdown
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html
import sys
import os

###################### Déclarations des widgets ######################

button = widgets.ToggleButton(description='click me')
out = widgets.Output(layout=widgets.Layout(border = '1px solid black'))

Server = os.listdir('/home/tim/Bureau/Servers/')
ServerList = widgets.Dropdown(options = (Server))

Date = ['2019-10', '2019-11', '2019-12', '2020-01']
DateList = widgets.Dropdown(options = (Date))


@interact(ServersList = Server, DatesList = Date)
def print_all(ServersList, DatesList):
    Test = os.listdir('/home/tim/Bureau/Servers'+ '/'+ ServersList+ '/'+ DatesList+'/')
    Path = os.path.join('/home/tim/Bureau/Servers'+ '/'+ ServersList+ '/'+ DatesList+'/' + str(Test).strip("[]").strip("''"))
    display(Path)

    df = pd.read_csv(Path)
    df.head()


    fig = px.line(df, x = 'Date', y = 'Total', title='DF command graph')
    fig.add_scatter(mode='markers+lines')

    display(df)
```

This script works perfectly, the output is :
[image]

My second script allow to display the CSV and trace a graph according to the FS choose in the dropdown. The script is :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('/home/tim/Bureau/Servers/Server1/2019-10/Test1.txt')


items = ['All']+sorted(df['FS'].unique().tolist())


def view(x=''):
    if x=='All': display(df)
    display(df[df['FS']==x])

    fig = px.line(df[df['FS']==x], x = 'Date', y ='Total', title='DF command graph')
    #fig.add_scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Used'])
    fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
    fig.show();

w = widgets.Dropdown(options=items)
interactive(view, x=w)
```

This script works perfectly too. The result is :
[image]

So my question is : How to merge my two script to have the three dropdown at the same time in order to choose the server, the date and the FS needed ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you are happy with `dash` it shouldn't be too complicate to figure out these callbacks.